# ARCore's AugmentedImages rotation

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, arcore

I'm making an AugmentedImage as a trigger to my AR Application. After detecting the image/trigger, I create an Anchor and attach to it different 3D objects as parent. These Objects will move according to it in different Axis : X,Y,Z.

The problem is that ARCore often misses the correct rotation of the Image. This will make a catastrophic impact to the experience because the X & Z Axis could be inverted. 
So my 3D Objects will move up/down instead of right/left.
How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

The only solution that I found for the moment is to test the orientation `(eulerAngles)` of the detected image before creating the anchor.